# How to get the Window title, Process ID of a windows pop up or dialog box?

Tags: c#

I am working on a browser automation, a "Choose file to upload" window will be triggered at a point from the browser. How do i retrieve the window title of the "Choose file to upload" window as "Choose file to upload"? (Using internet explorer)

I have tried to obtain all existing window titles using **Process.MainWindowTitle** but it returns the the Browser window title twice whereas I want the Title to be returned as "Choose file to upload" and the Browser window Title. Does the Pop up window not generate a new file explorer process ? Also, I was able to get 2 PIDs with respect to the Browser Window title ( one for the browser and one for the Pop up ). How do i get the PID of the Pop Up alone ? I get no PIDs when i search with window Title name as "Choose file to upload"

Comment: The "Choose file to upload" dialog isn't a process.

Comment: What browser are you using? Can you show us some code?